# Caption label font

Tags: fonts, captions

For captions I like to use *condensed* `iwona` font. So far I managed to obtain only the *standard* `iwona`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}
    \DeclareCaptionFont{myfont}{\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont}
    \captionsetup[table]{font={myfont},
                         labelformat=uc,
                         singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{My table caption}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What `\fontfamily` selection should I make so that the chosen font will be the *condensed* version of `iwona`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iwona` package option `condensed` appends a `c` to the font name, so the font name for Iwona Condensed is `iwonac`.

There are four versions of the font: Regular, Regular Condensed, Light, and Light Condensed:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}
    \DeclareCaptionFont{myfont}{\fontfamily{iwonalc}\selectfont}
    \captionsetup[table]{font={myfont},
                         labelformat=uc,
                         singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\test[3][]{#3 & \fontfamily{#2}\selectfont#1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \test{iwona} {Iwona Regular}
  \test{iwonac}{Iwona Regular Condensed}
  \test{iwonal}{Iwona Light}
  \test{iwonalc}{Iwona Light Condensed}

  \test[\bfseries]{iwona} {Iwona Regular Bold}
  \test[\bfseries]{iwonac}{Iwona Regular Condensed Bold}
  \test[\bfseries]{iwonal}{Iwona Light Bold}
  \test[\bfseries]{iwonalc}{Iwona Light Condensed Bold}

  \test[\itshape]{iwona} {Iwona Regular Italic}
  \test[\itshape]{iwonac}{Iwona Regular Condensed Italic}
  \test[\itshape]{iwonal}{Iwona Light Italic}
  \test[\itshape]{iwonalc}{Iwona Light Condensed Italic}

  \test[\scshape]{iwona} {Iwona Regular Small Caps}
  \test[\scshape]{iwonac}{Iwona Regular Condensed Small Caps}
  \test[\scshape]{iwonal}{Iwona Light Small Caps}
  \test[\scshape]{iwonalc}{Iwona Light Condensed Small Caps}

  \test[\itshape\bfseries]{iwona} {Iwona Regular Bold Italic}
  \test[\itshape\bfseries]{iwonac}{Iwona Regular Condensed Bold Italic}
  \test[\itshape\bfseries]{iwonal}{Iwona Light Bold Italic}
  \test[\itshape\bfseries]{iwonalc}{Iwona Light Condensed Bold Italic}
\end{tabular}

\newcommand\testweight[1]{#1 & \usefont{T1}{iwonac}{#1}{n}\selectfont Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \testweight{bx}
  \testweight{b}
  \testweight{eb}
  \testweight{l}
  \testweight{sb}
  \testweight{m}
  \testweight{ebx}
  \testweight{lx}
  \testweight{sbx}
  \testweight{mx}
\end{tabular}

\pagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{My table caption}
    \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

---

Iwona is a very complete set of fonts, most combinations of family, shape, and series are available.

There are four families, as I said above, named `iwona`, `iwonal`, `iwonac`, and `iwonalc`. Form here you can't (easily) select them by name like that, but you have to use LaTeX's font selection system. If you do `\fontfamily{iwonalc}\bfseries` you get “Iwona Light Condensed Bold”. The same applies to all other font switches. Unfortunately the documentation seems to show only the OpenType fonts.

To get a grasp of what font faces are available you can look at the four font definition files for Iwona in your TeX distribution: `t1iwona.fd`, `t1iwonal.fd`, `t1iwonac.fd`, and `t1iwonalc.fd`, for each of the four font families, where you'll see the available shapes and series.

Basically you can select the family with `\fontfamily` then add any font switch command you want. You can also use the lower-level `\usefont` command with `\usefont{encoding}{family}{series}{shape}`. For instance Iwona Regular Condensed Bold, which you asked in the comments, can be used with either:

```
\usefont{T1}{iwonac}{b}{n}\selectfont
```

or

```
\fontfamily{iwonac}\bfseries
```

In the example above I showed the available font series for `iwonac`. For other fonts see the font definition files I mentioned above. There are too many fonts (which is good :), so I didn't show them all here.

Comment: thank you for answer (+1)! it almost solve all my problems ...  now i have two questions: -) :  (i) where i can find names for all `iwona` version (so far my searching was unsuccessful);  (ii) does exist boldface condensed `iwona`? if exist, pleas add it to presentation of fonts.

Comment: @Zarko You're welcome :) I added a bit more explanation on how to select the exact font you want. I didn't show all of the possible combination because they are many, but it's quite easy to get any one of them with the basic font switches.

Comment: thank you very much! now i have a collection for `iwona` fonts versions too!